# Need to split entry points with the number of user comes first

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+
| STudent_ID | Marks | Subject | EntryPoints   |
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+
|          1 |    50 | Maths   |          10   |
|          2 |    50 | Maths   |          10   |
|          3 |    45 | Maths   |          10   |
|          1 |    30 | History |          20   |
|          2 |    30 | History |          20   |
|          3 |    30 | History |          20   |
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+
```

Expected output:

```
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+ 
| student_id | Marks | Subject | TotalPoints   | 
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+ 
|          1 |    50 | Maths   | 5             | 
|          2 |    50 | Maths   | 5             | 
|          1 |    30 | History | 6.66          | 
|          2 |    30 | History | 6.66          | 
|          3 |    30 | History | 6.66          | 
+------------+-------+---------+---------------+
```

Total points calculation

For maths Entry points is 10 and number of student scored maximum is 2 so 10/2 = 5
for history Entry points is 20 and number of student scored maximum is 3 so 20/3 = 6.66

Query I tried:

```
select student_id,marks,subject from
(
select student_id,marks,subject,dense_rank() over ( partition by subject order by marks desc) rn  from test
) t
where rn=1
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------+---------+ 
| Student_id | Marks | Subject | 
+------------+-------+---------+ 
|          1 |    50 | Maths   | 
|          2 |    50 | Maths   | 
|          1 |    30 | History | 
|          2 |    30 | History | 
|          3 |    30 | History | 
+------------+-------+---------+
```

I am not getting how to get the total points column in my query

Comment: Is the maximum a fixed parameter or is it just the max among rows with the same subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the max score is the max among all the marks with the same subject.

```
SELECT 
    Student_ID
    ,Marks
    ,T.Subject
    ,CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), 
       CONVERT(float, EntryPoints)/
       CONVERT(float, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY T.Subject))) as 'TotalPoints'
  FROM @T T
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Subject, MAX(Marks) OVER(PARTITION BY Subject) 
  as Max_Marks FROM @T) Scores
  ON T.Subject = Scores.Subject

  WHERE Marks = Scores.Max_Marks
  ORDER BY Marks DESC, Student_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group by` with your query for getting the count of subject, then `join` the result with the same query.

as next:-

```
Select a.student_id,a.marks,a.subject, 
Cast(a.EntryPoints as decimal ) / cast(b.CountPerSubject as decimal) TotalPoints   
from 
(
select student_id,marks,subject ,EntryPoints
    from
    (
            select student_id,marks,
            subject, EntryPoints,
            dense_rank() over ( partition by subject order by marks desc) rn  

            from test
    ) t
where rn=1
) a

Left Join
(
    select subject, count(subject) CountPerSubject
    from
    (
    select student_id,marks,subject ,EntryPoints
    from
    (
            select student_id,marks,
            subject, EntryPoints,
            dense_rank() over ( partition by subject order by marks desc) rn  

            from test
    ) t
where rn=1 ) c

group by subject) b
on a.subject =  b.subject
```